# loop problems make frequency table in R

Tags: r

```
library(MASS)

with (survey, 
  for (variable in names(Filter(is.factor, survey))) {
    print(table(variable))
  }
)
```

I'd like to make frequency tables for all factor variables.
But, it doesn't work.

need some help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is another solution:

```
lapply(Filter(is.factor, survey), table)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a slight modification that works.

```
for (variable in names(Filter(is.factor, survey))) {
  print(table(survey[[variable]]))
}
```

To use `with()` with a character as you have tried you *could* do (not necessarily recommended):

```
with(survey, 
  for (variable in names(Filter(is.factor, survey))) {
    print(table(eval(as.symbol(variable))))
  }
)
```